# How to create sets and name it

Tags: alphabet

I have a requirement to create a document similar to the attached image. I am working with Sanskrit alaphabets and there is a name for each set as shown in the image. In english there is no set other than broad division of Vowels and consonants. I could have posted image with Sanskrit text but lot of people here do not have that font.

I would really appreciate your help.
one way I thought of was, to create nodes around each letter in Tikz but not sure if there is any easy method out there. 
[image]

PS: I could not think of a good question title

I am adding output based on @Yori's solution. Everything work great except I did not get straight lines. I guess the issue is with Devanagari fonts. I highlighted the issue with red circle, the line is not horizontal its slanted. Sorry I could not attach image to my comment to I am modifying here. if you feel I should start a new question I can do that as well. 
[image]

Comment: That's because the right-most character is higher than the other characters, so the node containing it is bigger, and hence its north point is higher. To fix this, I think you can replace `nodes={font=\bfseries}` by `nodes={font=\bfseries, minimum height=24pt}`. This makes sure the height of each node is at least 24 points. You have to play a bit with the 24pt to see what works best for you. I hope the horizontal alignment will be ok. (For debugging purposes you can add `draw=black`, so that you can see the nodes containing the characters.)

Comment: @Yori - Worked great, thank you for all your help

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `TikZ` to accomplish:
[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) 
      [matrix of nodes, nodes={font=\bfseries}] {
       A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I & J & K & L & M & 
       N & O & P & Q & R & S & T & U & V & W & X & Y & Z \\
      };

  \def\h{8pt}

  \draw [thick] (m-1-1.north) -- +(0, \h) -- 
     node [anchor=south] {First set} 
    ($(m-1-5.north)+(0,\h)$) -- ($(m-1-5.north)$);

  \draw [thick] (m-1-9.north) -- +(0, \h) -- 
     node [anchor=south] {Second set} 
    ($(m-1-13.north)+(0,\h)$) -- ($(m-1-13.north)$);

  \draw [thick] (m-1-18.north) -- +(0, \h) -- 
     node [anchor=south] {Third set} 
    ($(m-1-22.north)+(0,\h)$) -- ($(m-1-22.north)$);

  \draw [thick] (m-1-1.south) -- +(0, -\h) -- 
     node [fill=white] {Complete set of characters} 
    ($(m-1-26.south)-(0,\h)$) -- ($(m-1-26.south)$);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: how can I attach an output image to ask a question, related to the solution you offered? do I start a new question for that?

Comment: @Raama: If the answer fully answers your original question, then yes you should post a new follow-up question. If it doesn't then you should edit your question to clarify what you want.

Comment: @Raama: See [How can I upload an image to be included in a question or answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2136/5764)

Comment: @Werner - I wanted to upload image to comment so that I will be related to this question. However I think there is no way I can upload an image to the comment. I can only edit the question and add an image.

Comment: @Raama: That is correct. If you do want to upload an image as part of a comment, upload it first as part of your regular question. This will give you an Imgur link. Then use *that* link in your comment and remove it from your post (or just cancel the edit to your post). Comments are meant to be non-rich and short, but that's a way to do it. Using that approach ensures that the image link doesn't expire, since Imgur's StackExchange account provides that longevity (see [New Image Upload Support](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/) entry on [so]'s blog).

Answer (score 12):

Some overlapping braces allow for this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\mystrut}{\rule[-.3\baselineskip]{0pt}{\baselineskip}}
\newcommand{\firstset}{\text{\mystrut A\ B\ C\ D\ E}}
\newcommand{\secondset}{\text{\mystrut I\ J\ K\ L\ M}}
\newcommand{\thirdset}{\text{\mystrut R\ S\ T\ U\ V}}
\newcommand{\completeset}{\text{\mystrut A\ B\ C\ D\ E\ F\ G\ H\ I\ J\ K\ L\ M\ N\ O\ P\ Q\ R\ S\ T\ U\ V\ W\ X\ Y\ Z}}
\begin{align*}
  \underbrace{
  \rlap{$\overbrace{\phantom{\firstset}}^{\text{First set}}$}\firstset\ 
  \text{F\ G\ H}\ 
  \rlap{$\overbrace{\phantom{\secondset}}^{\text{Second set}}$}\secondset      \text{N\ O\ P\ Q}\ 
  \rlap{$\overbrace{\phantom{\thirdset}}^{\text{Third set}}$}\thirdset\ 
  \text{W\ X\ Y\ Z}
  }_{\text{Complete set}}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

`\rlap` provides a zero-width box with a `r`ight overlap. I've added a `\mystrut` to each of the sets to raise/lower the `\overbrace`/`\underbrace` away from the characters.

[`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) provides the `\text{...}` macro and `align` environment for convenience, although it is not really necessary in this instance.